# How to aggregate string using Linq 2 Entities

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, linq-to-entities, devexpress

I have an `IQueryable<Model>` of objects in my db. I need to cast them to `IQueryable<ViewModel>`

```
class Model 
{
    public Guid ModelId { get; set; }

    // some properties

    public virtual User Users{ get; set; }

}

class User
{
    public Guid UserId { get; set; }
    public string FirstName { get; set; }
    public string LastName { get; set; }
}

class ViewModel
{
    public Guid ModelId { get; set }
    public string UsersName { get; set; }
}
```

ViewModel.UsersName should be merged string of all users first and last names.
This **need to be a IQueryable** since I'll use DevExpress Mvc Grid and I'll need to pass it in this way. Grid handles the paging, so it needs to IQueryable.

I've tried:

```
IQueryable<ViewModel> viewModel = model.Select(s => new ViewModel()
        {

            UsersName = s.Users
                .OrderBy(d => d.LastName)
                .ThenBy(d => d.FirstName)
                .Aggregate(string.Empty, (s1, users) => users.FirstName + ' ' + users.Surname + ", ")
        });
```

but it's not translatable to linq to entities. I've also tried string.join() but it won't work neither.

The result string should be for expample : "Cecelia Leblanc, Sarah Hodge" ... etc.

Thanks for any input.

Comment: What do you need `UsersName` for? Perhaps it would be easier to this on the DevExpress grid (as it must have materiliazed the data at some point)

Comment: UsersName would be displayed on the grid as a column. Thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 2):

Usually view models/DTOs should not be too smart, but this is a case where a little bit of smartness comes in too handy for comfort. Create a view model like:

```
class ViewModel
{
    public Guid ModelId { get; set; }
    public IEnumerable<string> UserNames { get; set; }
    public string UserNamesString
    {
        get { return string.Join(", ", this.UserNames); }
    }
}
```

populate it by

```
var models = s.Models.Select(m => new ViewModel
                        { ModelId = m.ModelId,
                          UserNames = m.Users
                                       .OrderBy(d => d.LastName)
                                       .ThenBy(d => d.FirstName)
                                       .Select(u => u.FirstName + ' ' 
                                                  + u.Surname)
                        }).ToList();
```

and access the `UserNamesString` property from `models.AsQueryable()`.